# Machine learning job recommender

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am new to machine learning and currently trying to build a job recommender system. I would like to know if there are any available data sets for job vacancies that I could use.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linkedin data set for building job recommendation system. For this, you can install python linkedin API:

```
sudo pip install python-linkedin
```

You can also use data set available on Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/job-recommendation